# Binary Search Tree, cannot cast from Int to string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to code a Binary tree and am currently trying to get an 'inorder' function to work which takes in a binary tree containing integers and outputs the binary tree to a string in numerical order. However when I try to concatenate the integer to the end of the string I am receiving the error message **"Error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::string'.**

The code for the function is as follows:

```
void _inorder(node *tree, string &str)
{   
        if (tree != NULL)
        {
            _inorder(tree->left, str);
            str = str + (string)(tree->data);
            _inorder(tree->right, str);
        }

        cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: unrelated : use a function visit_node so your _inorder function can work with other elements or do something else

Comment: When you get an error message, you should at least read it to see which line it refers to (and mention that here).  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::to_string`(since c++ 11) to convert the `int` to a `string`.

```
str = str + std::to_string(tree->data);
```

Comment: Note: This is a C++11 feature, so it might not be available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Before c++11, you can do this:

```
ostringstream os;
os << tree->data;
str += os.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
  std::to_string(int);
```

This should resolve the error.